# TCP simple client for a robot server. Not sending data

Tags: sockets, tcp, client

I am writing a simple TCP client so that I can connect to an UR (Universal Robot) robot, and send messages (popup XXXX) to the port number 29999, to generate popup messages in the UR screen. UR server does not respond correctly to the gethostbyaddr neither gethostbyname functions when connecting, so, for testing, I connect directly to the IP and Port. The code of the simple TCP client is as follows:

```
int initTCPSocket(void)
{
    struct in_addr ip;
    struct hostent *server;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    { 
        printf("ERROR opening socket");
        return -1;
    }
    portno = atoi(serverPort.c_str());

    if (!inet_aton(serverIP.c_str(), &ip))
        printf(" ERROR: error parsing IP address %s", serverIP.c_str());
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(ip.s_addr);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("ERROR connecting to server");
        return -3;
    }
    else
        printf("Connected to server");
}
```

The code that actually sends data is:

```
bool SendDataTCP (tekniker_tcp_comms::SendDataTCP::Request &req, tekniker_tcp_comms::SendDataTCP::Response &res)
{
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        ROS_INFO("ERROR in connection");
        res.dataSent=false;
        return true;
    }

    size_t msgLength = req.msg.data.length();
    //write to connected server.
    int n = write(sockfd, req.msg.data.c_str(),(int)msgLength);
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        ROS_INFO("ERROR writing to socket");
        res.dataSent=false;
    }
    else
    {
        ROS_INFO("write %d bytes. Message %s",n, req.msg.data.c_str());
        res.dataSent=true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I obtain messages of correct connection, and I can call the Service, and the write function works ok, but, no popup appears in the UR. It seems the UR does not receive correctly the messages. 
Connecting to the UR server for popup messages using ncat ( ncat 172.16.205.2 29999) and sending messages manually works fine.

After debugging for some hours, I can not find any cause for this problem. I would appreciate a lot any kind of advise,

Thank you in advance,

Comment: There is no code here that either sends or receives anything, but I will state that these problems about 'not sending' generally resolve to 'not receiving correctly'.

Comment: I have added the code for sending data. The thing is that by using "ncat" the communication works, but no with my client. I can not detect the difference...

Comment: Great, now all we need  is the code that receives it, and we will have a real question that humans can answer.

Comment: Yes, if I had the code maybe I would not have the problem either....its a robot controller, as said in the question, and it is propietary and closed. I appreciate your irony, though.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting Wireshark to monitor TCP/IP, the problem was with the LF termination character, that was not correctly sent.
Solving this problem the client has worked correctly.